# No audio from Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, 19.10

I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu on my laptop. But there seems to be no audio from the speakers.
I tried many fixes mentioned on this forum such as force starting the alsamixer selecting the correct driver the GUI as well as Pluse Audio.

```
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS [8086:a348] (rev 10)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Sound
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Cannon Lake PCH cAVS [1462:1228]
--
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:10f0] (rev a1)
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

These are the audio devices that the system recognizes.
Can anyone please guide me to the steps in fixing this issue?
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I am not an expert, but did you try this?

```
echo "options snd-hda-intel model=generic" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/06/fix-no-sound-dummy-output-issue-in.html

This has fixed a similar problem on my computer (Ubuntu 18.04).
Best regards.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Will try this after going home

Comment: I tried it, it didnt work out. :(

Comment: This worked for: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10) snd card on a 
Asus ROG Strix GL703 laptop

Answer (score 0):

This is almost two years old, but did you check the volume on your headset?  I have a cannon lake in a system 76 system and somehow the speaker volume is tied to the headset volume.  I've tried for a LONG time (after Groovy Gorilla was launched) to fix this, but essentially, I pretty much have to run:

`amixer -c 1 set Headphone 100% unmute`

I think the unmute can also be "mute" as it is only the volume you need.  Also, your card number (the -c 1 part) might be different.  It doesn't matter whether or not the headset it muted as it doesn't mute the speakers (unless they're muted, then you'll ALSO not get sound).  Finally, if you actually plug in headphones, you'll likely have to run this again when you remove them.

If anyone can figure out how to separate the two volumes, that would be GREAT... as that would be a real fix.